# setTargetFragment in dialogfragment not work - android

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-dialogfragment

I am calling a `DialogFragment` in another `fragment` like bellow:

```
@CoursesFragmentScope
class CoursesFragment : DaggerFragment(),
    DefaultLifecycleObserver,
    CourseTypeListDialogFragment.ApplySelectedCourseTypeFilter {
    @OnClick(R.id.btnCourseType)
    fun btnCourseTypeClick() {

        val fm = activity!!.supportFragmentManager
        val courseTypeListDialogFragment =
            CourseTypeListDialogFragment()
        courseTypeListDialogFragment.isCancelable = false
        courseTypeListDialogFragment.setStyle(
            DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE,
            0
        )
        courseTypeListDialogFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 1)
        courseTypeListDialogFragment.show(fm, "")
    }
}
```

And my `DialogFragment` is like bellow:

```
class CourseTypeListDialogFragment: DaggerAppCompatDialogFragment(), CourseTypeAdapter.CourseTypeListener {
    interface ApplySelectedCourseTypeFilter {
        fun applySelectedCourseType()
    }
..some code..
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view)
        iApplySelectedCourseTypeFilter = targetFragment as ApplySelectedCourseTypeFilter
     }
..some code..
}
```

But get me bellow `error` in this line:

```
courseTypeListDialogFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 1)
```

And say me:

```
Fragment CourseTypeListDialogFragment{92f4a96 (cbe1689e-1367-4436-8de6-3797320e7d41) } declared target fragment CoursesFragment{422cc09 (9d16e30b-fd71-44a8-8c45-8a866b62c135) id=0x7f0800d5} that does not belong to this FragmentManager!
```

What can I do?

Both classes are from same package:

```
import dagger.android.support.DaggerAppCompatDialogFragment
import dagger.android.support.DaggerFragment
```

I removed `courseTypeListDialogFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 1)` and opened dialog but not work my `interface` in `dialog`.

I am using from `fragments` in `activity` like bellow:

```
class MainActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity() {
    @BindView(R.id.nav_view)
    lateinit var navView: BottomNavigationView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super<DaggerAppCompatActivity>.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        ButterKnife.bind(this)

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
        navView.menu.findItem(R.id.navigation_courses).setIcon(
            IconDrawable(this, MaterialCommunityIcons.mdi_account_box)
                .colorRes(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
                .actionBarSize())

        navView.menu.findItem(R.id.navigation_login).setIcon(
            IconDrawable(this, MaterialCommunityIcons.mdi_login)
                .colorRes(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
                .actionBarSize())

    }
}
```

Comment: how did you add the. CoursesFragment did you use supportFragmentManager?

Comment: @  Fahad Alotaibi. Updated my question.

Comment: this issue is with fragment manager see the updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line

```
val fm = activity!!.supportFragmentManager
```

to

```
val fm = fragmentManager
```

read the following blog
https://medium.com/better-programming/what-is-target-fragment-da0e7c7f345c

Comment: @ Fahad Alotaibi. I can't find any childFragmentManager.